# Windows user added from "net rpc" command is disabled

Tags: linux, windows, bash, rpc

I'm trying to create a Windows user local account from Linux bash.

I use the following command from Linux server in order to create "foo" windows local account on Windows server:

```
net rpc user add foo password -SWindowsHostname -UwindowsAdminUser%windowsAdminPassword
```

After executing the command, "foo" was correctly created on WindowsHostname server as local account but it is set as "Disabled".

I opened the "Foo" account properties (from lusrmgr window) and the options in the General tab are:

- User must change password at next logon (selected)
- User cannot change password (disabled - not select-able)
- Password never expires (disabled - not select-able)
- Account is disabled (selected)
- Account is locked out (disabled - not select-able)

Is there any way to enable account using Linux server with `net rpc` command or create account already enabled?

In the documentation of `net rpc user add` command I saw -F option:

```
(net [<method>] user ADD <name> [password] [-c container] [-F user flags] [misc. options] [targets])
```

But there isn't any explanation of this "user flag" and how to use the -F option.